# Getting the result of a python method in java returns unexpected results

Tags: java, python

I am trying to print out the return of a method in python inside of java.
This is my python code, inside of the file file1.py:

```
def main():
    return(5)
```

And here is my java code:

```
import java.io.*;
public void sampleMethod(){
    try{

        System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start file1.py main()"));
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Failed" + e);
    }
}
```

When I run, it returns `java.lang.ProcessImpl@12a337b`. Every time that I run, everything after the `@` symbol is different and seemingly random.

Comment: Your Python code doesn't do anything except define a function btw. `main` is nothing special in Python, and the entry point of *every* python script is simply the first line.

Comment: The main reason I have a function in the python script is so that there can be a return statement, which I thought might have been the problem.

Comment: Right. But your script doesn't do anything in the sense that you shouldn't expect *any* output. It looks like you are printing some Process object. You should look at the docs for examples of how to get the standard output of your process. But again, your python script doesn't print anything to stdout

Comment: So here's the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html it looks like you need to use the `getInputStream` method, which will return some file-like object I'm sure (that you'll likely have to `.read` from)

Answer (score 1):

The string `java.lang.ProcessImpl@12a337b`  you see is
the `toString()` result of the `Process`returned by
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("....")`.

Instead of this you probably want the see the exit-code of this process (`5` in your case).
For getting it you must wait for the process to finish and then get its exit-code:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start file1.py main()");
process.waitFor();
int exitCode = process.exitValue();
System.out.println(exitCode);
```

For more info see the javadoc of [`Object.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--), [`Process.waitFor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--) and [`Process.exitValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue--).

Comment: I suspect they actually want to read from stdout of the process.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
System.out.println("Failed" + e);
```

You are printing out the `IOException` object with the default `toString()` method. You want to use the [`getMessage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage()) method:

```
System.out.println("Failed" + e.getMessage());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
interpreter.exec("import sys\nsys.path.append('pathToModules if they are not there by default')\nimport yourModule");
// execute a function that takes a string and returns a string
PyObject someFunc = interpreter.get("funcName");
PyObject result = someFunc.__call__(new PyString("Test!"));
String realResult = (String) result.__tojava__(String.class);
```

try it